# Circular Reveal com mudança de cor do background e status bar em TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de fazer um efeito que ao clicar no TabItem as cores de fundo e status bar mudem com o efeito circular de revelação, similar ao do Google Play Store como mostra na imagem, sou iniciante e não encontrei nenhum tutorial ensinando isso por enquanto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]